# What's the easiest way to build a delta robot using LEGO Mindstorms 51515?

Tags: part-identification, technic, mindstorms, robot-inventor

I'm fairly new to Lego Mindstorms and I'd like to assemble a pick and place mechanism.

I was looking for existing delta robot designs and found a lot of good looking designs:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbXBTZhhlYs&ab_channel=HiroLaboOECU
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGPw-bnQF-k
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmMKpRE4X5w
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bs1SoyfvZ4Y
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjV4PJEjDKg (not a delta, but still a parallel robot)

The majority are use Lego NXT. I'd like to use Mindstorms 51515 and hope it's a matter of swapping servos, maybe some minor part adjustments (due to difference in servo dimensions) and porting the code over.

The HiroLabo delta robot looks the simplest to me (but I might be wrong, so please correct me). What are the parts used for the arms and circular base (labelled as parallel links and universal joints) ?

[image: HiroLabo Delta Robot screenshot displaying parts]

[image: HiroLabo Delta Robot screenshot displaying parts]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What are the parts used for the [Hirolabo delta robot's] arms and circular base (labelled as parallel links and universal joints) ?

Let's see another still from that video:

[image: parts inventory]

There I see:

- [2736 Technic axle 1L with tow ball](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2736)
- [32293 Technic, 1x9 link](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32293), AKA "Technic steering link 9L"
- [4185 Technic wedge belt wheel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4185)
- [41678 Technic, axle and pin connector perpendicular double split](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41678)
- 2L pins
- 4L axle
- Red ball

> I'd like to use Mindstorms 51515 [...]

Well, I'm looking at the [parts list for 51515](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=51515-1) and am seeing no universal joints and only four towball axles. Seems like you'll need to replace each universal joint with two perpendicular joints.

Working with a limited selection of parts is always challenging, but I think 51515 has everything you need. Try something like this for the actuator and the base of the parallelogram:

[image: sketch, base]

The key is using [6536 Axle and Pin Connector Perpendicular](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6536) to provide the extra degree of freedom. It's gonna be worse than a universal joint or a ball-and-socket joint, but it's what you've got. Remember to use the [low-friction gray pins](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3673&idColor=86) for the joints (instead of the [high-friction black ones](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2780&idColor=11)).

I've drawn only one arm, but the other one is symmetrical; and I haven't drawn the pins - add them as needed.

The top part would also use two connector blocks, and perpendicular-axle-pin-connectors for the arms:

[image: sketch, upper]

Since 51515 doesn't have any parts with an hexagonal pattern, or any other easy way of achieving a 120° angle, you'll have to rely on interconnecting the upper assemblies (with [3L pins](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6558&C=7)):

[image: sketch, 3]

That still looks flimsy, so consider reinforcing the assembly with more interconnections.

You'll need to fiddle and test, but I think this design should provide you with a solid base to start tinkering with.

Also note that the joints in this design are lacking a degree of freedom, and that this might apply excessive **torsion** to the beams used in the six arms. Experiment with adding an additional 6536 perpendicular-axle-pin-connector to each joint to provide that extra degree of freedom.

---

Of course, you can always go shopping for more parts. In your case, you would only need twelve of [32474 ball joint](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32474) and [93571 ball joint socket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93571). You should be able to acquire those from the usual marketplaces (pick-a-brick, bricklink) for about 0.5$/0.5€ each pair, or about 6€/6$ the full set.

Welcome to the rabbit hole of "I just need to buy one more of that one piece".

Comment: "low-friction black pins for the joints (instead of the high-friction blue ones)" - are we talking about the same pins I'm thinking about, where the black have the extra friction ridges and the blues don't? <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2780>

Comment: My bad, I had in mind the 3L blue pins with friction and the 2L blue pin+axle with friction. The 2L pins without friction are the grey/bley ones.

Comment: OMG this answer is amazing! Thank you so much for the detailed information: much appreciated !